# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError (Using Flask)

Tags: python, flask

i got this error.

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'phone_num' in 'field list'")
[SQL: INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone_num, msg, date, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)]
[parameters: ('First ', '000000000', 'fyfyfu', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 15, 15, 56, 24, 470775), 'Aavjfbsjfb@GMAIL.COM')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

Comment: 1054, "Unknown column 'phone_num' in 'field list' - first check if you have phone_num column in your database. When adding a new question please follow instructions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have phone_num column in database.

Comment: Try to run this query directly in mysql `INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone_num, msg, date, email) VALUES ('First ', '000000000', 'fyfyfu', NOW(), 'Aavjfbsjfb@GMAIL.COM')` and check if you will get the same error.